# Issue running Kvasir over CGC Challenge Binaries

Tags: c

I am attempting to run Daikon over CGC Challenge Binaries as found on https://github.com/trailofbits/cb-multios, which are written in C. However, when I try to process the application with the Kvasir front end, the application seg faults for reasons unknown to me.

I am working with Daikon version 5.8.3, cloned and built from the git repo https://github.com/codespecs/daikon. I built both Daikon and Kvasir following exactly the instructions in the README, and was able to successfully run them both over the provided C examples. I also cloned the CGC Challenge Binaries from the previously mentioned cb-multios repo and built them as per the README. However, running Kvasir over any of the built binaries results in the aforementioned segmentation fault.

I am running on Ubuntu version 20.04 and have attached a screenshot of the error in question.
[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWF0u.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please never attach screenshots. Instead use backticks like so: ``` code/error goes here ```

Comment: Please read [ask] and post an [mcve].  Have you tried debugging the program?